# Dynamic import - import() - fails when the code is packaged into an executable

Tags: node.js, import

I am working in a `commonjs` environment trying to dynamically import an `es` module

Consider the below code :

```
const mysqlController = (async function () {
    try{
        var {default:dateformat}= await import('dateformat');
        // also tried await import('../../../node_modules/dateformat/lib/dateformat.mjs')
    }
    catch(e){
        console.error('Line 31 of db_controller');
        console.error(e);
    }
// More stuff
})()
```

The statement `await import('dateformat');` works fine when debugging. But when using `pkg` to produce a standalone executable, it gives the following error:

```
TypeError: Invalid host defined options
```

Could somebody tell me what is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, for some reason node executables made with package [pkg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg) doesn't honor `import()` statements.

As a temporary workaround, I made `cjs` alternatives for the `es` modules which I was trying to import using [rollup](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/).
Then, I copied the bundle locally and `require`d those.

Comment: Just to confirm I get this same problem  on pkg version 5.6.0  which uses Node.js version 16.14.2 it seems.  I'm trying to import a .mjs file from a .js file. This is a show-stopper.

Answer (score 0):

Vercel/pkg does not (yet) support import of ES6 modules.

The reason seems to be that pkg must traverse all require()-calls in your program to know what exactly needs to be packaged together into the exe it creates. It does not know it should do a similar thing with all and any import-statements in your program as well.

SEE: https://github.com/vercel/pkg/pull/1323